# RealmSwift使用の際のデータ移行方法

Tags: swift, ios, realm

Realmを利用させていただこうかと思っております。ただ使い道が一度作成したモデルを基にデータを保存、ユーザが行った処理に基づいてデータが保存されていく仕様になっております。その際のデータはアプリがアップデートされたら消えてしまうのでしょうか？iOSアプリのアップデートの際のデータ移行処理等の方法があればお教えいただきたく存じます。何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

＊アップデートの際のモデルは変更は特にしないつもりです

以下モデルになります

```
class　UserClass: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var usr: String = ""
    let colorData = List<UserData>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "usr"
    }
}

class UserData: Object {
    dynamic var usrData = NSData()
    let chidLink = LinkingObjects(fromType: UserClass.self, property: "usrData")
}
```

Comment: 結構これ愚問なのは半信半疑理解しているつもりですが全く方法がないののか知りたい次第です。方法がなければバッサリとお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmのデータは普通のファイルとして保存されます。特に何もしなければ、アプリケーションのアップデートで消えたりすることはありません。

デフォルトではDocumentsディレクトリに保存されますが、保存先を変更したり、ただのファイルなのでコピーすることも可能です。

`/Library/Caches`や`/tmp`ディレクトリはシステムがパージ可能な領域なのでそこに保存した場合はディスク容量が少なくなったときなどにシステムによって削除されることがあります。

RealmというよりはiOSのファイルの扱われ方の話なので、下記の資料などが参考になると思います。

[今こそ復習したい、iOSアプリのディレクトリ構成](http://qiita.com/tototti/items/8646405f47cc56a59722)

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。

Comment: 追加の質問で申し訳ないのですがもしRealmのバージョンが上がった場合データがなくなることはありますでしょうか。お手数おかけしますが返答よろしくお願いします

Comment: Realmのバージョンが変わってもデータはなくなりません。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。